# Can tinkering with global Python pip break the OS?

Tags: python

I ran `pip freeze` on my 16.10 (I know) and saw that some packages are provided by Ubuntu.

```
adium-theme-ubuntu==0.3.4
cryptography==1.5
python-cloudfiles==1.7.10
ubuntuone-client-data==14.4
unity-lens-photos==1.0
```

Ubuntu uses Python for system needs. But are their stuff put away in a virtualenv? If I upgrade `requests` by the default`pip` to a non-forward compatible major version, will it break Ubuntu packages that uses `requests`?

Comment: FYI, Ubuntu 16.10 has gone EOL for a while. Please consider upgrading to 17.04 (or 17.10 soon) or downgrading to 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Those are managed by apt. People running `sudo pip` and installing packages have been known to run into problems. It's  best if *you* stick your pip usage in venv and leave the system to itself.

Comment: @muru are people who run pip as non-root users safe?